# Ability to bookmark an answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmarks

Sometimes I see some answers which are really good and I'd like to save. Similar to how we follow questions I'd like to have the ability to 'save' answers implemented in this site

Comment: Tag suggestion: Should we create a [tag:bookmarks-favorites-follow] umbrella tag? Ideas?

Comment: @Qmechanic Is there any reason to not keep them as separate tags?

Comment: @FakeMod: The problem is if users don't find related posts in searches because they are marked by different tags. E.g. recently SE decided to rename favorites as bookmarks.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes. We should merge the bookmarks and favorites tags, however, "following" is quite a different thing. This is solely my opinion, it may not be the correct one. Moreover, "following" (as Glorfindel said in his answer) is yet under development, so we may expect a few more changes regarding "following" in near future.

Comment: Sure it is different, but is it really sufficiently different to warrant a different tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't bookmark an answer, but you can *follow* it. This is a [new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) which isn't completed yet; at the moment, there's no list of followed posts in your profile, but this will be implemented soon.

[image]

One of the downsides may be that you receive notifications about edits and comments on that answer; for a full list of differences, see this [proposed FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345783/295232).

A temporary workaround might to use the bookmark system of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can "favorite" a *question*, by clicking the star symbol under the vote tally. Your favorite questions *are* listed in your profile.  It's unusual on our site for a question to have more than a handful of answers, so that might accomplish what you want.

[image: Screen capture with red circle]